# xAuth authentication in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, afnetworking, xauth

How would I go about working with xAuth authentication in an iOS app? I've used [this library](https://github.com/romaonthego/AFXAuthClient) in the past, but it hasn't been updated for AFNetworking 2.0 and is very buggy as is anyway.

Is it possible to do with NSURLConnection or NSURLSession easily? Is it built into AFNetworking 2.0? I'm trying to figure out how I would best go about tackling xAuth in iOS.

It's not for Twitter either, a ton of APIs require xAuth for authentication.

Comment: This fork supports AFNetworking 2: https://github.com/mzygar/AFXAuthClient.  AFNetworking is a general purpose HTTP library, and doesn't have built-in support for xAuth, etc.  AFNetworking 2 is very modular, so it should be simple to review this code and make it work the way you want.  I know of anything that you can just drop in with no work though.

Comment: @AaronBrager I've tried that fork, and the general bugginess of the library still remains unfortunately.

Comment: Well, the answer is, unfortunately, to fix the bugs…  feel free to post questions here if you get stuck.

Comment: I was hoping for a bug free library is all.